# What to install to make XSLTProcessor work?

Tags: php, xslt, php-5.3

I am using PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.11
LibXML is enabled:

```
dom
DOM/XML     enabled
DOM/XML API Version     20031129
libxml Version  2.7.6
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support     enabled
```

But, when I write: `$XP = new XSLTProcessor;` The parser has no idea what I am talking about. I use autoload...can't find a file to include.
What am I missing?

Comment: *(reference)* http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsl.setup.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
--with-xsl[=DIR]
```

where DIR is the libxslt installation directory

when you do a manual ./configure, make, make install of PHP from source

or

```
sudo apt-get install php5-xsl
```

might work